# Python Google App Engine If

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates

Hey I'm new to Python and Python Templating and Google App Engine and i'm trying to display a card with a error if the error exists.

```
        {% if {{error}}!="" %}
        <div class="row center-align">
            <div class="col s12 m6 l6 center-align">
                <div class="card red lighten-1">
                    <div class="card-content white-text">
                        <p>{{error}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
```

This seems like the logic way do it but i'm having the a error. Any ideas on how do this?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Just saying "a error" tells us nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need variable tags when you're already inside a template tag.

```
{% if error != '' %}
```

or just

```
{% if error %}
```